# How can I increase the timeout for the temporary EC2 credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am using IAM roles to access S3 from my EC2 instance calling the following end point.

curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access.

The response I get -

{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2017-12-07T06:29:59Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "AASDJCJNSDPLB5FZA",

"SecretAccessKey" : "/vKFYv4AFlarEspnSNSKD87SDNSDFx3EsJv",

"Token" : "FQoDYXdzEIj//////////wEaDBUN1g6SxPkVQ46UjyKcA0l0q7jpEphFkq1OR3TD3Zm180bKKfkUqYeG6Xr/537olhJWKT2GGdkl/kDXIg3WxxBBOafy+yl4jgn0XTrTT2DWOX+ETPLvjZ4vpfrMNfVP0kwZiWbOuk4GcruixVdiuuDM6cce3WxZprFMLIe5WI0jVkpdA/MQQkqVsIsVcsVMa5LdhUsgdLQ3Yo+82BXVMpccjo+jeYqKEvm3h9rk9XmVRlPxn0wHzHgyiUgIl9O3U6/Ocp+hai+L8JzH5EH8O9ystJvf/rPQyZi0tVmsadasdasdydZr4NPtGYiTEye0dWHOhNvUNg8ZzQ9iBSZzUH8YxgtuOsM8C4LESNubVUxj4d9D49Krzs+oc2lFzLvQaEsSosn+V2mLlGq/AtPHwvyVQvlEOD7Uo27+j0QU=",

"Expiration" : "2017-12-07T12:39:23Z"

============================

I want to increase the expiration time "2017-12-07T12:39:23Z" of the temporary credentials. Can someone please help?

Comment: Why not just use rules and aws cli?

Comment: Because my code is in written in Spring Framework and it's not compatible to use IAM roles yet. My other python app server works astoundingly well with IAM roles.

Comment: Spring Framework works perfectly fine with IAM roles, there is no incompatibility.  Just create your S3 client and use normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to increase the duration the credentials obtained by instance profile and the instance/EC2 will [rotate the credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) automatically.

Also, you don't have to curl the metadata url to get the credentials. AWS CLI and SDK can be used to get the credentials from the metadata itself.

Comment: curl was just to initiate the thread, I am using AWS SDK (java and python) to getting these credentials but was trying to find out if there is a way to increase the timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary Security Credentials are short term and they are refreshed for some duration. From your question you have mentioned that the code block to access the S3 bucket is running inside the EC2 instance from where you are using the CURL command to get the credentials.

As per AWS best practices it's better to user the **Instance profile credentials**, so that you don't need to worry about the credentials expiry time. [Read More Here Instance profile credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)

**Also we can increase the duration of the credentials**. For that you have to use the AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS) to get the credentials.

> AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS) to create and provide trusted
>   users with temporary security credentials that can control access to
>   your AWS resources

Here the duration can be configured to last for anywhere from a few minutes to several hours. Here is the chart of various time configurations of AWS STS API's

[image: AWS STS APIs Comparison]

For more about this you can AWS STS API [Refer Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html) and about Temporary Credentials [Refer Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html)

Comment: Note that the OP **is already using** instance profile credentials.  That's what's being obtained with curl.  The difference is that aws-cli and the SDKs automatically make the necessary recurring requests to the metadata service before each set of credentials expires.  You can't change the timeout of these credentials, you have to refresh them yourself if you are managing them yourself.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, does anyone know what the credential lifetime is when you use a role / instance profile?

Comment: The response contains fields `LastUpdated` and `Expiration`. The query I just send shows a lifetime of over 6 hours. Also the response does not change. I guess until the credential is about to expire.