# AWS EC2 IMDS instance role credentials expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

When I attach a role to an EC2 instance

[image]

I'm able to retrieve temporary credentials for that role from within the instance, via

```bash
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: ${TTL1}"`
curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/InstanceProfileRole1
```

The expiration time for the retrieved credentials (the `Expiration` field) is always around 6 hours in the future. (Regardless of the value I set for `TTL1`)

Is there a way to control the expiration/duration of the credentials that IMDS returns? I tried looking in official AWS documentation but couldn't find anything about that

Comment: When you launch EC2, you can optionally provide an instance profile to pass an IAM role to the EC2 instance. The credentials you're retrieving from IMDS are temporary STS credentials, they expire after 6 hours and are refreshed automatically, and they are associated with the instance profile. I don't see any option on the [RunInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html) API to supply a different expiration time.

Comment: You're conflating the metadata *token* ttl and the IAM *Credentials* TTL.  Two totally different TTLs.

Comment: Have you tried using `iam:UpdateRole` to set the maximum session duration?

Comment: @user3553031 looks like updating the session duration has no effect on the expiry time of the temporary credentials

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I increase the timeout for the temporary EC2 credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689902/how-can-i-increase-the-timeout-for-the-temporary-ec2-credentials)